# UITabBarViewController wont display as expect

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

My goal: clicking a button in View A will bring me to view 1 which is a UITabBarViewController containing View 2 and View 3.

What I am doing is:

```
-(void) goToView1 {
    View1 *controller = [[View1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View1"bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

and all the xib files are describe in a below image
[image]

However, after running the application, what I got is

[image]

Can anyone advice me on this issue please?

All comments are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You have taken UITabBarViewController and you are trying to navigate to a view. If you want to navigate to a view then use UINavigationController